# Segmentation fault (core dumped) after calling vfprintf function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here's the code

```
static FILE *flLog = nullptr;
const char logFilename[] = "log.txt";

void logprintf ( const char *fmt, ... ) {

    if ( flLog == nullptr ) {
        flLog = fopen(logFilename, "a" );
        if ( flLog == nullptr )
            return;
    }

    time_t rawTime;
    struct tm * timeInfo;

    time ( &rawTime );
    timeInfo = localtime ( &rawTime );

    fprintf( flLog, "[%d-%d-%d %02d:%02d:%02d] ", 
             timeInfo->tm_year, timeInfo->tm_mon, timeInfo->tm_mday, 
             timeInfo->tm_hour, timeInfo->tm_min, timeInfo->tm_sec);

    va_list ap;
    va_start( ap, fmt );
    vprintf( fmt, ap );
    vfprintf( flLog, fmt, ap );
    va_end( ap );

    fprintf( flLog, "\n" );
    printf( "\n" );
    fflush( flLog );
}
```

I just can't figure out what's wrong with that. The function's weird that it works well when it's provided 2 arguments, but give segmentation fault when it's provided 3 or more arguments.

And somewhere in my project, the where has been called:

```
logprintf("Security warning: %s tried to give a invalid VUA (%s).\n", ip, vua);
```

After calling that, I got this output:

```
[1]    9770 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./build/apps/server
```

Comment: Compile with `-g` and run with `valgrind`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Basically, simplify the code as much as you can while still reproducing the error. There's a good chance you'll find the bug along the way, and if not, you can post what's left and make our task much easier.

Comment: Consider using `strftime()` to format the date/time into a string.  Your code would print `120-0-1` for the date component of New year's Day 2020-01-01 (if it wasn't crashing), which isn't an obvious format to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've passed a `va_list` to a function, you must use `va_end()`.  The preamble to the standard specification of [`<stdarg.h>`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16p3) says:

> The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.<sup>253)</sup>
>
> <sup>253)</sup> It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns.

You have:

```
va_list ap;
va_start( ap, fmt );
vprintf( fmt, ap );
vfprintf( flLog, fmt, ap );
va_end( ap );
```

You need:

```
va_list ap;

va_start(ap, fmt);
vprintf(fmt, ap);
va_end(ap);

va_start(ap);
vfprintf(flLog, fmt, ap);
va_end(ap);
```